# Obtener valor de una jTable con mysql y colocarlo en un spinner java

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Buenas noches, alguien me puede orientar como obtener el valor de una jtable y colocarlo en un spinner? con los campos de texto no he tenido problemas, pero con el spinner ni siquiera me aparece mensaje de error pero no obtengo el valor de la fila que se ha hecho click, el campo edad en mysql es un entero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la fila seleccionada de un `JTable` se utiliza el método `getSelectedRow().` Intenta con

```
tblPersonas.getSelectedRow()
```